# powershell replace data in files sub directory (ok) only if line begins with some specific string (ko)

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

it s ok to replace a string in all files sub directory  :

initial in line : 02#APPLICATION/PDF;name="**P31F9B000A00001.pdf**"*
replace by  : #
P31F9B000A00001 can be anything

code :

```
$array = @("D:\cebi")
$myRegExp1 = [regex]"#APPLICATION/PDF;name=""(.*).pdf""\*"
$myRegToReplace1 = "#"

foreach ($element in $array) {
    Get-ChildItem $element  -Recurse -Include "*.DAT" | foreach-object {Copy-Item $_.fullname ($_.fullname+".bak") -recurse } 
    gci $element -r -include "*.DAT"| foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |  foreach-object { $_ -replace $myRegExp1,$myRegToReplace1 -replace $myRegExp2,$myRegToReplace2  }  | set-content $a }
```

}

But now, i would like do replace a string only for the lines  begins by a specific string

i want to replace string "ClasseAutomatique" by "ok_man" only if line begins with "02#APPLICATION/PDF;name="
intial string :

```
02#APPLICATION.PDF;name="anything_data.pdf"-anything_data.2016.##_ClasseAutomatique_2016__##anything_data.pdf
01#APPLICATION.PDF;name="anything_data.pdf"-anything_data.2016.##_ClasseAutomatique_2016__##anything_data.pdf
```

Result would be :

```
02#APPLICATION.PDF;name="P31F9B000A00001.pdf"-anything_data.2016.##_ok_man_2016__##P31F9B000A00001.pdf
01#APPLICATION.PDF;name="P31F9B123D02651.pdf"-anything_data.2016.##_ClasseAutomatique_2016__##P31CKB000D00002.pdf
```

i try this  :

```
$myRegExp3 = [regex]"^(02#APPLICATION/PDF;name=(.*).pdf)-(.*).2016.##_ClasseAutomatique_2016__##(.*)"

$myRegToReplace3 = "$1-$2.2016.##_ok_man_2016__##$3"

$1 would be 02#APPLICATION/PDF;name=(.*).pdf
$2 would be data in (.*) 
$3 would be  (.*)
```

but nothing. if someone can have a solution to build the line with replacement

Answer (score 0):

ok here the result :

```
$myRegExp3 = [regex]"^(02#APPLICATION/PDF;name=)(.*)ClasseAutomatique\*2016\*(.*)$"

$myRegToReplace3 = "`$1`$2*ClasseAutomatique*2016*Faux*`$3"

`$1 get first block = (02#APPLICATION/PDF;name=)
`$2 get second block = (.*)
`$3 get third block = (.*)
```

all code :

```
$array = @("D:\cebi")
$myRegExp3 = [regex]"^(02#APPLICATION/PDF;name=)(.*)ClasseAutomatique\*2016\*(.*)$"

$myRegToReplace3 = "`$1`$2*ClasseAutomatique*2016*Faux*`$3"

foreach ($element in $array) {
gci $element -r -include "*.dat"| foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |  foreach-object { $_ -replace $myRegExp3,$myRegToReplace3  }  | set-content $a } 

}
```